# Electric field and Electric problem confusion

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Question is:

Determine the charge of an object of mass 1g, that is suspended by a wire vertically. When we applicate an electric field $\overrightarrow{E}=(2\sqrt(3)\overrightarrow{i}+1\overrightarrow{j}).10^5 V.m^-1$, in the quilibrium, the mass is inclined by an angle of $\theta = 30$  (see the figure below.)

What i did was:

$\sum \overrightarrow{F}=\overrightarrow{0}$

$\overrightarrow{P}+\overrightarrow{T}+\overrightarrow{F_e}= \overrightarrow{0}$

with $\overrightarrow{F}=q\overrightarrow{E}$

by projecting:

in $(X'OX)$ :

$Tsin(\theta)+qE_x=0$ with $P_x=0$

$Tsin(\theta) = -qE_x ...(1)$

in $(Y'OY)$ :

$Tcos(\theta)-mg+qE_y=0$

then: $Tcos(\theta) + qE_y = mg ..(2)$

from $(1)$, we get $T=-\frac{qE_x}{sin(\theta)}$

we replace in $(2)$, we get:

$-\frac{qE_x}{tan(\theta)}+qE_y=mg$

hence : $q=\frac{mg}{-\frac{E_x}{tan(\theta)}+E_y}$
$q=\frac{10^-2}{(-6+1)10^5}=-2*10^-8C=-20nC$

Conclusion: $Q=-2$nC

[image: problem]

What i find weird with my solution is, why would the charge be negative if there is repulsion? We applicate a positive electric field from the right, isn't the mass with the negative charge supposed to incline towards the right and not the left? I'd very much appreciate it if someone can clear my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always draw the electric field as well. The answer is simple: no.

The elctric field points like this $\nearrow$, so the force on a **negative** charge will be opposite $\swarrow$.

The reason is that force is $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$. If charge is negative, force is opposite the electric field. So the force is pulling in the opposite direction $\swarrow$, which should incline the ball as it is drawn.

Comment: So nothing is wrong with my solution? I know that if the charge is negative the force is opposite the electric field, but what if the problem is with my calculated charge? what if it's actually positive? if it's positive then the repulsion would actually happen.

Comment: Provided that you did the last steps correctly, then yes. You stated that $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$, without worrying about the sign of the charge. Equilibrium equation is giving you the charge to be negative. It's like you made an assumption that "charge is positive", and you get that the value must be actually negative. That's just you chose wrong bnetween 2 options, but the math is the same with both, so the very math will give you a negative output.

Comment: More accurately, you are "predefining" a sign, but not forcing it to be positive. You're assuming it will be positive, but then the answer gives you a negative solution. It's all right, because it can be any real number. It's like when you presume that two forces go in the same direction. Equilibrium will tell you that one of those must be negative, alright, you just change the picture.

Comment: I have one more question, if the picture given in the problem had the wired inclined towards the right and not the left, the solution wouldve changed right? due to the x component of the wire force being negative. It depends on the side the wire was drawn right?.

Comment: Yes, but you'd find that the charge would have to be possitive. Otherwise there would be no possible equilibrium... unless you don't know the angle $\theta$. If you let the angle as a free parameter, you'd find two solutions: one upside and one downside.